# Python comparison in a list of lists of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I am new on python and I have a question about comparison in list of tuples.
I have a list with duplicates of the second element in the tuple and I want to print only the first appearance of this tuple.
For example, for this list:

```
[(1, 2), (5, 10), (6, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35)]
```

I have this function:

```
def func(lst):
    list_first = []
    #Checks if 2 elements have the same second value.
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if(lst[i][1] == lst[i+1][1]):
                    first =  (lst[i][0]),lst[i][1] 
                    list_first.append(first) #append only the first element
    print list_first
```

My function's output is:

```
[(5, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35)]
```

But my expected output is:

```
[(5, 10), (24, 35)]
```

How can I fix it?

***UPDATE***

I have to do all this algorithm on list of lists.
So for the input:

```
[[(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3)], [(5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3), (9, 3)], [(10, 3), (11, 3), (12, 3), (13, 3), (14, 3)]]
```

I want the output to be:

```
[[(0, 3)], [(5, 3)], [(10, 3)]]
```

I'v tried oh change the solutions I'd got here.
But all I'v got was:

```
[[(0, 3)], [(0, 3)], [(0, 3)]]
```

Comment: Try running the program on paper with different examples including this one [(1, 2), (5, 10), (6, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35), (40, 35)]. That will show you some problems with the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

A solution for your question using `groupby` from `itertools` module:

**Edit:** Like what @AKS suggests, here is a function with multiple form of inputs.

```
from itertools import groupby

def comp_list(a = list()):
    final = []
    for _, v in groupby(sorted(a, key = lambda x : x[1]) , lambda x : x[1]):
        b = list(v)
        if len(b) > 1:
            final.append(b[0])

    return final

a1 = [(1, 2), (5, 10), (6, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35)]
a2 = [(1, 2), (5, 10), (6, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35), (40, 35)]
a3 = [(5, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35), (20, 5), (15, 4), (21, 5), (13, 4)]
a4 = [(1, 2),(6, 10), (5, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35)]

print(comp_list(a1))
print(comp_list(a2))
print(comp_list(a3))
print(comp_list(a4))
```

Output:

```
[(5, 10), (24, 35)]
[(5, 10), (24, 35)]
[(15, 4), (20, 5), (24, 35)]
[(6, 10), (24, 35)]
```

Comment: You don't really need to write the code 3 times to demonstrate examples. Why not create a function which take `a` as input and return `final` as output? And, then you can show these one or more examples as you wish.

Comment: But `a = [(1, 2),(6, 10), (5, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35)] ` gives me [(5, 10), (24, 35)]`

Comment: @MikeMüller Check now, i've updated my solution. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Much better. But you still loose the order: `a5 = [(24, 35), (30, 35), (1, 2),(6, 10), (5, 10)]`--> `[(6, 10), (24, 35)]`. Order preserving would be: `[(24, 35), (6, 10)]`. But it is not clear from OP question if this matters. ;) But sorting can be expensive for large lists compared to a `O(n)` loop and some `O(1)`dict and set look-ups.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMüller for your comment. Can you point me to some books or websites in which i can learn how calculate the complexity of an algorithm. Like what i said in my profile i code for fun because i love it. And i'm lacking for ressources.

Comment: [This](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) gives you an overview of Python's time complexity. Some [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and something to [get started](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/).

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeMüller

Answer (score 2):

### Solution without assuming sorted input

You can use a dictionary that uses the second value in the tuple as key.
If the this key appears the second time, append the already seen tuple to your result. Don't append again if you see the tuple a third or more time. 
The set `added` contains the already added second tuple entries if there are more than two occurrences found:

```
from __future__ import print_function # makes work in Python 2 and 3

def find_first(lst):
    seen = {}
    res = []
    added = set()
    for elem in lst:
        key = elem[1] 
        if key in seen and key not in added:
            res.append(seen[key])
            added.add(key)
        else:
            seen[key] = elem
    return res
```

Testing with a lis. Note the last element `(60, 10)` with the `10` repeating a third time:

```
L = [(1, 2), (5, 10), (6, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35), (60, 10)] 
print(find_first(L))
```

Output:

```
[(5, 10), (24, 35)]
```

It does **NOT** use sorting and works for this example data:

```
L = [(1, 2), (6, 10), (5, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35), (60, 10)] 
print(find_first(L))
```

Output:

```
[(6, 10), (24, 35)]
```

The solution from the other answer does not work for this data:

```
from itertools import groupby

L = [(1, 2), (6, 10), (5, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35), (60, 10)]  
final = []
for _, v in groupby(sorted(a) , lambda x : x[1]):
    b = list(v)
    if len(b) > 1:
        final.append(b[0])

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[(5, 10), (24, 35)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small method that can help you here

```
def removeDuplicateTuple(sampleList):
    uniqueList = []
    entryLog = {}
    processedEntries = []
    for x, y in sampleList:
        if entryLog.get(y)==None:
            entryLog[y] = (x,y)
        else:
            if(entryLog.get(y) not in processedEntries):
                uniqueList.append(entryLog.get(y))
                processedEntries.append(entryLog.get(y))

    return uniqueList
```

test:
`[(1, 2), (5, 10), (6, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35), (45, 2)]`

output:
 `[(5, 10), (24, 35), (1, 2)]`

Comment: Result for `L= [(1, 2), (6, 10), (5, 10), (24, 35), (30, 35), (60, 10)]` is `[(6, 10), (24, 35), (6, 10)]`.